# XPATH : replace every ohter whitespace

Tags: xpath, replace

I'd like to replace every other (odd?) space with `x`. The result should be:

> axb axb axb axb axb

I tried something like:

```
replace ("a b a b a b a b" , " " , "x")[position() mod 2 = 0]
```

-- but with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: `fn:replace` requires an XPath 2.0 (or XQuery) compatible query processor.

You cannot use `fn:replace` with an predicate like this. There is no array-like access to characters in XPath (like you're used to from eg. C). You probably could also solve this using `fn:tokenize` and a for-loop, but that's getting things rather complicated.

Your query did not return any result, as there is exactly one result (single element string sequence), but the predicate only returns every second.

---

Use a regular expression instead. This expression matches on non-space (`\S`) and space (`\s`) and replaces those patterns by a version with `x` in between. The star quantifier in the end is important for odd number of match groups (like in your example).

```
replace("a b a b a b a b" , "(\S+)\s+(\S+\s*)", "$1x$2")
```